# Synchronous architecture with asynchronous repository

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, architecture, promise

In order to keep clean architecture of my node.js microservice I have controllers, services and e.g. repositories.

I want a synchronous data flow: controller -> service -> repository -> service -> controller. In this flow (in simple user story) repository returns data to service and service to controller. But repository should process requests to external storage in a asynchronous way. All asynchronous code should exist only in repository, service should obtain raw data.

My current implementation:

UserController.js

```
module.exports.create = function() {
    console.log("In controller: before service call");

    let userDto = JSON.parse(this.request.body);
    let savedUser = userService.createUser(userDto);

    console.log("In controller: after service call");
};
```

UserService.js

```
module.exports.createUser = function createUser(userDto) {

    let user = require('../domain/user/User');

    user.login = userDto.login;
    user.password = userDto.password;

    let userRepository = require('../infrastructure/user/UserRepository');

    Q.spawn(function* () {
        console.log("In service before promise resolve");

        let savedUser = yield userRepository.createUser(user);

        console.log("In service after promise resolve");

        return savedUser;
    });

    console.log("In service: after repository call");
};
```

UserRepository.js

```
module.exports.createUser = function createUser(user) {
    console.log("In repository: before save call");

    return new Q.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

        userEntity.save(function(err, savedUser) {

            console.log("In repository: inside callback after save call");

            if (err) {
                console.log("In repository: inside callback before reject");
                reject(Error('Błąd zapisu danych!'));
            } else {
                console.log("In repository: inside callback before resolve");
                resolve(savedUser);
            }
        });
    });
};
```

Logs:

- In controller: before service call
- In service before promise resolve
- In repository: before save call
- In service: after repository call
- In controller: after service call
- In repository: inside callback after save call
- In repository: inside callback before resolve
- In service after promise resolve

I would like to get the following sequence of logs:

- In controller: before service call
- In service before promise resolve
- In repository: before save call
- In repository: inside callback after save call
- In repository: inside callback before resolve
- In service after promise resolve
- In controller: after service call

Comment: Did you miss a log line in the target sequence?

Comment: Did You mean "In service: after repository call"? I think this log is less important. From the point of view of the described problem the most important sequence is from second log to sixth log: service makes synchronous call to repository, repository makes asynchronous call to remote storage (during this call node halts processing of current request), returned data from asynchronous call are returned to service.

Comment: You cannot create a synchronous interface to an asynchronous data store.  It just can't be done.  If any link in your chain is asynchronous, then the whole chain is asynchronous.